# How to add data into linked list and display it using button call in JFrame GUI using Java

Tags: java, user-interface, linked-list

I am currently creating an bookstore inventory application using linked list. I am having problem when it comes to add data into linked list in one frame and display it in another frame. It did not add the data into the linked list and so it displays nothing. How can this be solved?

This is my Node class:

```
public class Node 
{
    String name;
    String author;
    int isbn;
    int number;
    Node next;

    public Node()
    {
        name = null;
        author = null;
        isbn = 0;
        number = 0;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(String name, String author, int isbn, int number)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public int getisbn()
    {
        return isbn;
    }

    public int getnumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return next;   
    }

    public void setNext(Node next)
    {
        this.next=next;
    }
}
```

This is my LinkedList class:

```
public class LinkedList
{
    Node node = new Node();
    static Node head;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head=null;
    }

    public Node getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }

    public static void addNode(String name, String author, int isbn, int number)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(name, author, isbn, number);
        if (head == null)
       {
            head = newNode;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book Information has been added to the inventory.");
            return;
       }

            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book Information has been added to the inventory.");
            return;
    }

    public void deleteNode()
    {
         if(head==null){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The list was empty.");
    }
    else{
        head=head.getNext();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The data has been deleted.");
    }
}

public String displayNode()
{
    Node current;
    String output = "";

    for (current=head; current!=null; current=current.next)
    {
        output+="Book Name: "+current.getName()+" Author: "+current.getAuthor()+" ISBN Number: "+current.getisbn()+" Number of copies: "+current.getnumber()+"\n";
    }

    return(output+"NULL");
}
}
```

This is the JFrame class for insertion:

```
private static LinkedList list;

public AddBook(LinkedList list) {
    this.list = list;
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String name = jTextField2.getText();
    String author = jTextField3.getText();
    int isbn = Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText());
    int number = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList.addNode(name, author, isbn, number);
}
```

This is the JFrame class for display:

```
private static LinkedList list;

public DisplayInventory(LinkedList list) {
    this.list = list;
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    jTextArea1.setText(list.displayNode());
}
```

May I know what is the problem here?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but your realize that this: `LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    jTextArea1.setText(list.displayNode());` will always display nothing right? You empty the list and then display the contents of the list. You should not re-initiate the `list`

Comment: omg, yes I do know that! However, if I put `LinkedList list = LinkedList()` it will always have error, and I only learn this way to call another class. May I know how should I edit this?

Comment: I got it!!! Thank you so much!!! @RoelStrolenberg

Comment: No problemo, good luck!